# vue.js Why set value to $event.target.value when keyup didn't change binded data?

Tags: input, vuejs2

I am using Vue JS 2

Trying to filter out some unwanted characters(, . & / \ ' "), what I do is：

1. bind input data through v-model
2. filt out illegal char and set `filteredVal` to `$event.target.value` when keyup

```
    <template>
      <div id="app">
        <p>field1</p>
        <input type="text" v-model="name" @keyup="filterText($event)" />
        <p>name: {{ name }}</p>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
      name: "App",
      data() {
        return {
          name: ""
        };
      },
      methods: {
        filterText($event) {
          var filteredVal = $event.target.value.replace(/[.,/\\&‘“]/g, "");
          $event.target.value = filteredVal;
        },
      },
    };
    </script>
```

But when I enter illegal value(ex: test,), the input field value is different from `name`.

I know `this.name = filteredVal` can work as expected, but what is the difference?

[image: input test,]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

v-model will ignore the initial value, checked, or selected attributes found on any form elements. It will always treat the Vue instance data as the source of truth. You should declare the initial value on the JavaScript side, inside the data option of your component.
[image]
You can see this in https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html.

Comment: So I can only change value through binded data! Thanks for your reply :)